# How can i get my code to recognize my array values?

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach

I want to output my userdata in a html table. First I do a sql-query an get the multidimensional array 'users'. Now I want to output my data but I get an 'undefined variable: user' error in my html output.
The array $users is known in my code. The error only appears in the frontend but not in the IDE.

```
<? foreach( $users as $user ): ?>
     <tr>
         <td><?= $user['M_ID'] ?></td>
         <td><?= $user['Username'] ?></td>
         <td><?= $user['E-Mail'] ?></td>
     </tr>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: It might be because `<?` (aka short tags) are disallowed on your server (which they should, btw, as they've been discouraged for a while) and your foreach statement is therefore ignored (but not the `<?=`s which are different). Try replacing `<?` (the first and last ones) with `<?php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to use `<? ?>` is defined in your `php.ini` file. likely your server php.ini config is not configed for supporting this. so change your code to :

```
<?php foreach( $users as $user ): ?>
     <tr>
         <td><?= $user['M_ID'] ?></td>
         <td><?= $user['Username'] ?></td>
         <td><?= $user['E-Mail'] ?></td>
     </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

also thanks to @jeto`s comment